# Shift + Comma (<) key does not work as usual

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I'm not sure if this is a hardware problem or not, but in order to type the "<" character, I have to hold down shift+comma and then release shift before releasing comma. For all other keys, (!"£$%^^&*()?@~}{ etc..) I can just hold down shift and press the key I want to output.

This is VERY annoying when you're a Web Developer like me and need the "<" character all the time.

As per usual, I have updated the drivers and have ran a Windows Update and BIOS update. Nothing has helped.

Running Windows 8.1 (also not working in Ubuntu Live CD) on a i7 Processor, GT 650M, 8GB RAM Asus Laptop. I've contacted them and they're not sure what the problem is, and suggest I return it as it has a malfunctioning keyboard. If anyone has any other theories, that would be great!!

Does anyone know what it could be?

Much appreciation!

EDIT: Also, keyboard layout is correctly set to UK Layout.

Comment: First try a USB keyboard and see if it works right.  But if no other keys seem to malfunction and the keyboard is relatively new and has not had any liquids spilled on it then it's highly unlikely to be a hardware problem.  There is a chance that this is one of the "sticky key" settings in the "Ease of Access Center" -- that annoying thing that pops up if you touch the shift key too many times.

Comment: I have checked the ease of access control panel and turned everything off. It works with an external keyboard so I guess the problems lies within the laptop's hardware?

Comment: Seems unlikely that it would be laptop hardware, given that the hardware doesn't do any transformations of that sort.  But I suppose it's vaguely possible that the shift and comma keys share an X or Y line and that that line is slightly flaky and is not handling multiple keypresses right.  (Would expect to find a few other keys that fail similarly in that case, but it's hard to predict which ones, since the X-Y wiring is up to the manufacturer.)  Do you get a comma if you do it "wrong", or no key at all?  Have you tried shift and all the alpha keys?

Comment: It works with a USB keyboard plugged in which is why I think its hardware fault. What do you think?

Comment: The only problem with that theory is that the built-in KB driver is separate from the USB driver, and this could be a driver problem.

Comment: I've tried both versions of the KB drivers from asus' website. And it still occurs in Safe Mode. On a side note (which may or may not be related). When I startup my laptop and it boots into the log in screen and a random bunch of characters are automatically entered into the password box as if someone was leaning on the keyboard. I have to delete all these before entering in my own password. It's not a virus as it happened on day 1 when I first booted my laptop for the first time (without being connected to the internet).

Comment: Yeah, it's sounding like hardware.  Unusual but certainly not impossible.

Comment: Got an RMA  to get it repaired. Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: For similar questions see http://askubuntu.com/questions/789223/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292378/ .

Comment: Maybe water damage, have you tried using right shift instead?

Comment: @StefanDunn How did you solve the problem? I have exactly the same problem here. PC with Microsoft Keyboard, Windows 10. No matter which language layout ...

Comment: @Marcus I never found out I'm afraid -- the laptop was stolen during a break-in. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check your layouts. I had a "US" installed under "Hungarian" and it was totally messed up.
Ended up just removing every layout and installing what I needed. (Hungarian - Hungarian, and US - US.)

By the way some applications behaved really weird for me with Windows 8.1 and global layout switch, so you may also want to give that a shot. (There is an option to return to the application-specific layout switching at regional settings.)

Comment: See Original question, I have already checked the layout settings.

Comment: @StefanDunn: Did you check if it's not UK->US but US->US?

Comment: Its UK. The @ and " keys are correctly mapped

Comment: @StefanDunn - Might be worth changing the layout to US and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: It does :(. I've tried almost every combination of keyboard setup and accessibility to no provail.